# Cómo obtener automáticamente el código de país de los usuarios que ingresan a mi formulario de registro en php o Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy creando una pagina web y en mi formulario de registro quisiera capturar el código postal del pais de todo los usuarios que accedan al formulario

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor

Comment: Tu pregunta no se ajusta a [ask] y puede quedar cerrada, checa demás el [tour]

Comment: podrias usar una api

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta de un formulario no contiene esa información.

Lo que se suele usar para adivinar el código de país -e incluso la región dentro del país- son servicios de geolocalización de IP's: es decir, dada la ip, estos servicios te indican en qué zona geográfica se ubica.

No obstante, esta información es sólo aproximada, ya que se pueden dar muchas formas de soslayarla: mediante vpn's, por ejemplo. Y a veces no está disponible.

Una información que sí se facilita es el header Accept-language. Esta información indica qué idiomas maneja el usuario. Obviamente, no es lo mismo, pero si se indica que un usuario usa español de Argentina, es una aproximación también a lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar (https://opencagedata.com) que es un api gratuito y te ayuda a extraer toda la informacion del usuario usando las coordenadas.
subscribete y luego copia el key api y lo pegas en el codigo abajo donde dice (Tu key api).

const coordenadas = (posicion) => {
const { latitude, longitude } = posicion.coords;
fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${latitude}+${longitude}&key=Tu key api`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(console.log);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coordenadas, console.log)